# Is there any way to get a names of arguments of function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to make a wrapper function which will take a function as an input and will return a newly typed function which allow both a list of parameters and an object which contain parameter names as keys.

I have written the following code for that. The code works as expected. The problem is that I have pass an additional type which contains the keys as parameter name and value as type of that parameter. I want to do this dynamically. I want to access the names of the parameters

```
//I want remove this Args parameters and make it dynamically using F type.
function wrapper<F extends (...args: any) => any, Args>(func: unknown) {
   type ParametersList = Parameters<F>;
   return func as (...args: [Args] | ParametersList) => ReturnType<F>;
}
const add = (x: number, y: number) => x + y;
const wrappedAdd = wrapper<typeof add, { x: number; y: number }>(add);
```

The `Parameters` function returns a named tuple(which is a new feature I guess). Is  there any way we could get the names/labels of that tuple.  You can also suggest any other way.
Thanks.

###Edit:
Ok I after some research I found out that we cannot get the names of the parameters of the function. So now my goal is to shorten my code a little bit. In the above code where I am passing an object in place of `Args`. I only want to pass an array of strings.

```
const wrappedAdd = wrapper<typeof add, ["x", "y"]>(add);
```

I want to generate an object dynamically using this array. Thanks

Comment: Not all arguments may even have names. What if `func` has a rest parameter just like `wrapper` does? What should the names of the arguments passed as the rest parameter be? Usually if you need named arguments, you should be passing an object instead of positional arguments.

Comment: @cdhowie We can consider that the function will always have named parameters not rest parameters like `add` function

Comment: @cdhowie I think you didn't get my question. Consider if there is a function with all named parameters. Is there any way we can get those names as typescript tuple or array type?

Comment: @cdhowie No this doesn't answer my question. I want names a typescript type not in a variable at runtime.

Comment: Parameter names are not observable in the type system except as documentation for IntelliSense.  I’m sure there’s an existing q/a pair for this but I haven’t found it yet.

Comment: Does your `wrapper` function not just blow up at runtime if you call it with a single object instead of a list of parameters?

Comment: @jcalz Yes at runtime it will obviously not work. But I will write javascript code for that too.

Comment: I still don't know how to map `x` and `y` to parameters object

Comment: @captain-yossarian Oh. NP. I will go for some other approach. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to define any types in global scope.

```js
type Elem = any;

type Predicate<Key extends number, Value extends Elem> = Record<Key, Value>

type Reduce<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Result extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? Result & Predicate<0, H>
    : Arr extends readonly [...infer Tail, infer H]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? Reduce<Tail, Result & Predicate<Tail['length'], H>>
    : never
    : never;


function wrapper<F extends (...args: any) => any>(func: F):
    (...args: [Reduce<Parameters<F>>] | Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F> {
    return func
}

const add = (x: number, y: string, z: number[]) => x + y;

const wrappedAdd = wrapper(add);
const add = (x: number, y: string, z: number[]) => x + y;

const wrappedAdd = wrapper(add)({ 0: 1, 1: 'hello', 2: [1] }); // ok
const wrappedAdd2 = wrapper(add)(1, 'hello', [1]); // ok
```

Btw, no need to use type assertion here. I mean you can get rid of `as` operator

If you are interested in more examples of such kind of types, you can take a look on my [article](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce)

Here you have representation of `Reduce` type in almost pure JS:

```js
const reduce = <T,>(arr: T[], cache = {}) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return cache
    }
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        const [head] = arr;
        return { ...cache, [0]: head }
    }
    const [head, ...rest] = arr;
    return reduce(rest, { ...cache, [rest.length]: head })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAtlAvFAhgOxAbgLABQhokUACgE4QAmAlgMbrAQA8A0hCFBAB7ObUAzlEwBXRACMIFADRQAaujijovfkNgJEAPlRQAShHoB7CtXac5i5RG2Fi4aIeqj6rQlE9QAghQrc+CAFhQ3RqY0w4EF8KdBAWeCRtGQ8vQ0FROGAA9RCjU3NBYApaTABzOSwQXTQAbwBfVM8anz8coI0AbQBdJqgAfgMIDKy+gC5W-zUO4U7SgDNpKAAJXoIvAaGR7IAycio6RmYWAAY5Zbt1rwmY9uCoKjCIqKhOgDoPhaWAFXRaODkX38qz6g1+-zuGlC4Ui0T8cQSWkuG0GzlcrHBAK2mV2+xoDCYGL+cE6AHIEOVgAALUndc7aZHXEQQABu0nGzLZFHwRF581EmHowFoESgAHdYmBIBQWAAxSHCAAUHze6AoZUEEyqAEpULoqtpFfzBRNZdqxn1lR81RqJp00W4WGQ1ehEBBmBRBHKGd0oAAfcgut0er2y7S6lC6QzAUQUTDfRzeqC1PpUGNxqDG+iERq8kyYIoYajUPSKngTMSSaRyEATIolcpyABeFfEUgoPQjuh4UAA1FBcPYCPnCxL0FKaN5i3oxxOKIqwtRtYralAThMAIxyDcTUlUiBwODGUlyABMdo3vvq2pwUAA9HeoMYANaEEfZWeQahT6inmeS6UF2LZctygPcDyPE9XkvG970fF8gA)

Like @jcalz said:

> Parameter names are not observable in the type system except as documentation for IntelliSense

There is no way to infer parameter name in TS and put it into another type, so I decided to use index type.

`0` for first argument, `1` for second, etc ...

Regarding using argument names:

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements)

> There is one place where the differences begin to become observable though: readability.
>
> They’re purely there for documentation and tooling.

```js
const add = (x: number) => x + x

type Args = Parameters<typeof add>

type Infer = Args extends [infer R] ? R : never // number
type Infer2 = Args extends [x: infer R] ? R : never // number
```

Hence, I don't think it is possible in current version of TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Using numbers for keys of the object will kill the purpose. As the number of parameters will grow it will have same problem as passing the parameters individually will have

Comment: @MaheerAli I made an update

Comment: Is there any way we could pass an type as array of strings ourselves which will contain key names. And then we can use those keys to generate the object those keys and corresponding values from parameters tuple?

Comment: @MaheerAli could you please provide an example with expected result? to make sure we are in the same boat :)

Comment: Ok brother I updated the question.